# Shift data in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, lag, shift

I want to rearrange data in a matrix of n x 12 dimension where n are years and 12 are months.

My aim is to generate a new matrix.

Old matrix:

```
4   11  5   4   5   6   7   Nan 9   10  11  7 
13  14  15  5   17  4   19  20  21  22  23  24
```

New matrix, version 1:

```
Nan Nan 4   11   5   4   5   6   7   Nan 9   10  
11  7   13  14   15  5   17  4   19  20  21  22
```

New matrix, version 2:

```
4   5   6   7   Nan 9   10  11  7   13  14  15
5   17  4   19  20  21  22  Nan Nan Nan Nan Nan
```

I want to have the option to move forwards and backwards in time.

I'd be very grateful for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What approaches did you try? Where did your attempts go wrong?

Comment: I wanted to use the lagmatrix function but it requires a toolbox to be installed which is not free. Then I found circshift and timeshift but I don't know how to apply it correctly for my purpose.

Comment: You *could* use `circshift`, but you'd have to get your 2d array into a 1d vector, shift, and then put the NaN's in the proper locations. You could accomplish the same thing with array indexing, though. Of course you'd have to reshape the data back to a 2d array at the end. But if I were going to do a lot of shifting, I'd probably just store the data as a column vector and only reshape it when necessary. Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

I understand your proposed solution but I still have a problem. I show you my attempt, it's just for a time lag of three months which is my "test" lag.

```
ind=Stmp.data(:,2:end);
inv_ind=ind';  
ind_vec=inv_ind(:); 
shift_month = 3;  
if shift_month == 3;  
test=[nan; nan; nan; ind_vec];  
TEST=reshape(test, 12, [])  
end
```

The script fails when reshaping the vector to the matrix. Can you help me with this?
I'm sorry to post this as an answer, but I can't handle to post the code in a comment properly.

Comment: Rather than post this as an answer, you should edit your original question with the new information. To answer your immediate question, you're taking a vector with length divisible by 12, adding 3 elements to it, and then trying to divide the elements into groups of 12 again, which won't work. Try `test = [nan; nan; nan; ind_vec(1:end-3)]`